# Отрисовка изменений GridLayout в цикле. Как?

Tags: android, многопоточность, ui

Всем привет, столкнулся с проблемой связанной с GridLayout. Суть в том, что я прохожусь в цикле по всем ячейкам и при необходимости заменяю их, но изменения видны только после того, как цикл завершится, что влечет за собой нежелательное изменение ячеек на последующих итерациях(несколько пингвинов идут в одну и ту же ячейку, считая что она свободна, и заменяют друг друга). Есть ли способ обновлять всю таблицу на каждой итерации цикла?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

запуск цикла происходит при тапе на таблицу, в нём при подходящих условиях вызывается метод cellSwap

```
private fun cellSwap(currentPosition: Int, newIndex: Int) {

    var temp = table.getChildAt(currentPosition)

    table.run {

        removeViewAt(currentPosition)
        removeViewAt(newIndex)

        addView(temp, newIndex)
        addView(cell.createCell(), currentPosition)
    }
}
```

насколько я смог понять из этого ответа, проблема в потоках, но решить её я не в состоянии https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17914200/android-invalidate-each-time-a-loop-occurs

p.s. Весь код [тут](https://pastebin.com/Z21iMqti)

Comment: В итоге сделал костыль в виде массива в который копирую таблицу и все перемещения рассчитываю в массиве. После каждой итерации обновляю таблицу.